# Installing Mapnik 2.2.0 in windows 7 with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, path, mapnik

I've been trying to install mapnik on my computer for hours but what i always get when I import mapnik is `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found`.

I'm using Windows 7. The currently installed software is Geoserver from Opengeo suite.

**Here is my path**

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Python27;C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\lib
```

**My python path:**

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\bin;C:\\mapnik-v2.2.0\python\2.7\site-packages\;C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\bin\;
```

Comment: no luck either, someone know?

Comment: Hey @Joan, did you ever get this to work? I just checked again and following [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/springmeyer/5651701) I was able to run both the `c++` and `python` demos as well as `import mapnik` in a running python interpreter. I used the full SDK version, copied to install dir, set all the paths required, and it worked without issue.

Comment: well i did, it seems that my system lacks libxml2.dll so i copied it from mapnik folder into C:/Windows and voila it worked.

Answer (score 2):

#### Follow the [install instructions](https://gist.github.com/springmeyer/5651701)

> First ensure you have 32 bit python 27 installed.

You can do this by typing the following into a python shell

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('32bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

If you see `'64bit'`, try reinstalling [python](http://www.python.org/download/) with the `32bit` version (look for the "Python 2.7.5 Windows Installer" link).

After that,

- [Download](https://gist.github.com/springmeyer/5651701) the `mapnik` package (I tested it with the full SDK version)
- Extract the archive to `C:\mapnik-v2.2.0`
- Add `C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\lib;` and `C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\bin;` to your `PATH`
- Add `C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\python\2.7\site-packages;` to your `PYTHONPATH`

`import mapnik`

Comment: in python shell i see this Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (intel)] on win 32. after i run platform.architecture() and it shows ('32bit', 'WindowsPE') i try to run import mapnik but it's still says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\python\2.7\site-packages\mapnik\__init__.py", line 69,
in <module>
    from _mapnik import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: Did you download the 'runtime package' or 'Full SDK' version?

Comment: You need both `c:\\mapnik-v2.2.0\lib;` and `c:\\mapnik-v2.2.0\bin;` on your system path. I don't see them both there.

Comment: my system path contain C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\lib, but why are you using \\ instead of \? i download the runtime package, i have included the path you said but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on WinServewr 2008 R2. The solution I found is to install Microsoft Visual C++(x86) redistributable [package](https://npackd.appspot.com/p/com.microsoft.VisualCPPRedistributable/10.0.40219) 10.0.40219, because mapnik depends on it. This package comes with postgreSQL 9.3 x86, so when you install only Postgre x64 version you can have this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, even after I installed a 32-bit Python. I was getting the same error:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.`

What fixed it in the end was copying all the DLLs to my python executable directory. I assume there was some DLL-hell type action going on and it was linking to a DLL somewhere with the same name but without that entrypoint. What entrypoint it was looking for I do not know.

In the end it was all useless though because it turns out that there is no OSM (OpenStreetMaps) plugin for the 2.2.0 version, so I decided to do this on Linux instead.

See the table at https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/WindowsInstallation for the reference of a missing OSM plugin - execution results in a runtime error indicating the plugin could not be loaded.

I think Windows binary support for mapnik has been dropped so I don't expect much change here.